# How to connect crate database using .NET Npgsql client in docker environment

Tags: docker, npgsql, cratedb

Im using .NET Npgsql client for crate database [cratedb](https://crate.io/docs/npgsql/en/latest/) .Crate database is running as a docker, dcoker command is

```
sudo docker run -p "4200:4200"   crate
```

But when i connect database through Npgsql client there is no error shows but connection is not established

```
NpgsqlDatabaseInfo.RegisterFactory(new CrateDbDatabaseInfoFactory());
var connString = "Host=localhost;Port=4200;Username=crate;SSL Mode=Prefer;Database=doc";
await using var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
await conn.OpenAsync();
```

im running docker database in local machine.i can able  to access the admin UI through http://localhost:4200/.Also crate database installed (using executable ) is connected the Npgsql client. Python client have no issue with connect the docker. I don't under the actual problem.

```
import requests
from crate import client
connection = client.connect("localhost:4200")
```

Comment: Have you tried providing the the ip port and database name to `CrateDbDatabaseInfoFactory`? https://www.npgsql.org/doc/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlDatabaseInfo.html

Also is both python and .net running outside or inside another container?

Comment: im running crate docker in my local machine

Answer (score 3):

By default CrateDB listen to PostgreSQL protocol compatible clients on port `5432`, the port `4200` is listening to HTTP clients. See https://crate.io/docs/crate/reference/en/4.3/config/node.html#ports for further documentation.

So changing your docker command to

`sudo docker run -p 5432:5432 crate`

should solve this issue.

Comment: Additionally you need to change the port in your connection string to
`var connString = "Host=localhost;Port=5432;Username=crate;SSL Mode=Prefer;Database=doc";`